# ActionScript 3 move an object in local 3D space relative to global space

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, actionscript

I'm trying to do some 3D transforms with AS3 and I've run into a problem where I'm not sure how to make this work.

I have a list of boxes within a movieclip, where this movieclip is rotated slightly. Something like this (values are made up, just for illustration):

[image]

[Initial State](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CIy04.png)

Now what I would like to do is take one of the boxes from inside this group and move it to a position in the global space. Like so:

[image]

[Intended result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dMdb6.png)

How would I do this with ActionScript 3?

Comment: You need MouseEvent handlers and a call to the startDrag method. If that doesn't mean anything to you, Google both of those and you'll be off to a good start. If you already have both of those in your code, post it for us to see and tell us what errors you are getting.

Comment: Unless the startDrag converts the clip into global space coordinates, I don't see how this is related?

Comment: Are you trying to move it with action script alone?

Comment: Yes. Although this seems near impossible to do with the IDE itself. Since there is no way for me to see the collapsed 3D view.

Comment: Please post the code code you have so far.

Comment: I don't have much code so far. What I tried was to have a helper movieclip with the right rotation and position on stage and then get the relative transform to the group parent (shown in the image), like so:
`newLocation = MovieClip(root["posmarker"]).transform.getRelativeMatrix3D(this.parent).position;`

_this_ being the "item"

But this did not produce the correct coordinates.

Comment: Hmm this is complicated by the 3D aspect of your program. I'll invite your question now that you have some code for people to look at in hopes that it gets more attention from someone with a little more insight into the 3D coords.

Comment: To clarify my earlier comments, I misunderstood. I thought you were trying to have the user drag the content

Comment: You could play with Away3D and create a plane. Set the material to be whatever the content is and have attach a MouseEvent3D to it.

Comment: Unfortunately that's not an option for me. It has to use standard Flash functionality.

Comment: I'll suggest including a mention of "3D" in the question title to maybe attract interested parties along that vein.